# how can I get GeoJson data from a url in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, url, mobile, geojson

I am a beginner in kotlin and I would like to have the information contained in a url:

in my case I have a list of url, each url contains information formatted in geojson and I would like to get this information.
Does anyone have an idea of how I can do this?

here is an example of the url that can be found in my list :

https://database-geojsons-test.s3.amazonaws.com/COOPERATIVES/Maps%2520test/Exploitation/Alpha/Alpha.geojson

Comment: Can you at least post some of the urls here

Comment: absolutely I edited my post

Comment: so you want info that is inside the geojson file and not in the url itself your intentions are not clear from the question

Comment: I want to get all the information in the geojson

Comment: You are building it on android or is it a general kotlin project?

Comment: it a general kotlin project

Comment: To read GeoJson from URL see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49394844/kotlin-how-to-read-json-string-on-url; To parse GeoJson data from String use https://github.com/data2viz/geojson-kotlin/releases/tag/v0.6.0

Comment: It's not working, it's always go to the function onFailure(), but the url si valid

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's quite simple as I use Retrofit I created a method that will retrieve the json content

```
@GET
    suspend fun getGeoJsonData(@Url url: String) : String
```

and I could retrieve the content by calling this method for each json

Answer (score 1):

you can use Retrofit and add a Gson converterFactory. You can read more about it on the android developer web site.

Here is just an exemple:

```
private val BASE_URL : String = "http [your URL]"

val interceptor: HttpLoggingInterceptor = HttpLoggingInterceptor().apply {
        this.level = HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY
    }

val client: OkHttpClient = OkHttpClient.Builder().apply {
        this.addInterceptor(interceptor)
    }.build()

private val retrofit = Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
            .client(client)
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create()) //Converters can be added to support other types in body
            .build()
```

I hope that works for you :)